# How to create Sessions Manager in Yii2?

Tags: php, session, yii2

I'm searching for Create Sessions Manager page in `Yii2` Framework.

I am looking for solution to the following problems:

List all current sessions active in server, get user's information from sessions such as:
 1. username
 2. ip
 3. current url

Is there any example? I am new in `Yii`, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the official documentation: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html. If yes then please specify what problems you are facing?

Comment: @chinmay, that guide only for current session. I would like to list all sessions actived in server include: username, ip, current url

Comment: @HTiT I answer your question in details at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45537969/how-to-create-user-session-manage-system-in-yii2-with-dbsession/45537970#45537970)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DbSession](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-dbsession.html) which will store all your session in database, from which you can get all the information and can create your own Session Manager.

You can create your own custom DbSession class as per your convenient to store extra data like user id, etc.

Comment: thanks @Akshay Vanjare, I used DbSession to store all sessions, I added column user_id to session_table and my problem's solved.