# How to create user session manage system in Yii2 with DbSession

Tags: php, mysql, session, yii2, user-profile

Today when I want to create user profile page for my website and want to create system users can manage his active sessions in this system need

- View active sessions Browsers and platform
- See what is current session
- remove unwanted active sessions

How we can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Find this solutions to save my users `user_id` into session table

[Yii2 database session - store additional attributes and user information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966453/yii2-database-session-store-additional-attributes-and-user-information)

[Logging out specified user, listing who's online by using DB sessions](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/issues/92)

But there is another problem in implementing this issue: *how to classify user sessions based on their browser and platform, and I found this solution.*

I added another column to the session database, and inside it, using [this class](https://github.com/wolfcast/browserDetection) and the code below I saved the browser information and user platform information.

```
'components' => [
    //...
    'session' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession',
                'writeCallback' => function ($session) {
                    $user_browser = null;
                    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
                        $browser = new \BrowserDetection();
                        $user_browser = "{$browser->getName()}-{$browser->getPlatform()}" . ($browser->is64bitPlatform() ? "(x64)" : "(x86)") . ($browser->isMobile() ? "-Mobile" : "-Desktop");
                    }
                    return [
                        'user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id,
                        'last_write' => new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()'),
                        'browser_platform' => $user_browser
                    ];
                }
            ],
   // ...
]
```

**note :** you add other data to your session table

But to find the current session, I encountered a problem when I checked `Yii::$app->session->id` and returned the empty string value and I found the solution in the link below.

[Blank Session ID in Module's BeforeAction](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7310)

in Yii2-Advanced I create `frontend\components\baseController` and extend all controllers from it and create `beforeAction()` and open session in it something like this:

```
namespace frontend\components;
class BaseController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function beforeAction($action)
        {
            if (parent::beforeAction($action)) 
            {
                Yii::$app->session->open();
                return true;
            }
              return false;
    }
}
```

At the end I create ActiveRecord model for session database and use it in profile page to show or remove user sessions